# Modifying toString Circular Array Buffer

Tags: java, arrays

I have the java code and been able to come up with a toString as shown below in the code:

```
       public class CircularArrayQueue<T> implements QueueADT<T>
{
   private final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 100;
   private int front, rear, count;
   private T[] queue; 

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Creates an empty queue using the default capacity.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public CircularArrayQueue()
   {
      front = rear = count = 0;
      queue = (T[]) (new Object[DEFAULT_CAPACITY]);
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Creates an empty queue using the specified capacity.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public CircularArrayQueue (int initialCapacity)
   {
      front = rear = count = 0;
      queue = ( (T[])(new Object[initialCapacity]) );
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Adds the specified element to the rear of the queue, expanding
   //  the capacity of the queue array if necessary.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public void enqueue (T element)
   {
      if (size() == queue.length) 
         expandCapacity();

      queue[rear] = element;

      rear = (rear+1) % queue.length;

      count++;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Removes the element at the front of the queue and returns a
   //  reference to it. Throws an EmptyCollectionException if the
   //  queue is empty.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public T dequeue() throws EmptyCollectionException
   {
      if (isEmpty())
         throw new EmptyCollectionException ("queue");

      T result = queue[front];
      queue[front] = null;

      front = (front+1) % queue.length;

      count--;

      return result;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns a reference to the element at the front of the queue.
   //  The element is not removed from the queue.  Throws an
   //  EmptyCollectionException if the queue is empty.  
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public T first() throws EmptyCollectionException
   {
      if (isEmpty())
         throw new EmptyCollectionException ("queue"); 

      return queue[front];
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns true if this queue is empty and false otherwise. 
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public boolean isEmpty()
   {
      return (count == 0);
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns the number of elements currently in this queue.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public int size()
   {
      return count;
   }


   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns a string representation of this queue. 
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
  public String toString()
  {
    String result = "";
    int scan = 0;

    while(scan < count)
    {
     if(queue[scan]!=null)
     {
       result += queue[scan].toString()+"\n";
     }
    scan++;
    }

    return result;

  }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Creates a new array to store the contents of the queue with
   //  twice the capacity of the old one.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
  public void expandCapacity()
  {
    T[] larger = (T[])(new Object[queue.length *2]);   

    for(int scan=0; scan < count; scan++)
    {
      larger[scan] = queue[front];
      front=(front+1) % queue.length;
    }

    front = 0;
    rear = count;
    queue = larger;
  }
}
```

How can I modify my toString based on these output for my queue:

I want to Start with an initial String showing the number of cars
If the queue is empty, thenI will return the initial String.
If front is at, or ahead of, back
I want to add a line for each car from front to the end
then add lines for those from the start of the array to back-1
else I want to add a line for each car between front and back-1.

This is my current toString() :

```
public String toString()
   {
      String result = "";

      for (int scan=0; scan < rear; scan++) 
         result = result + queue[scan].toString() + "\n";

      return result;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote the pseudo-code, a few `if`/`else-if` blocks do the rest.

```
  public String toString()
  {
    String result = String.format("There are %d items in the queue.", count);
    if (count == 0)
    {
      return result;
    }
    else if (front >= back)
    {
      for (int i = front; i < count; i++)
      {
        result += queue[i].toString() + "\n";
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < back; i++)
      {
        result += queue[i].toString() + "\n";
      }
    }
    else
    {
      for (int i = front; i < back; i++)
      {
        result += queue[i].toString() + "\n";
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
```